# What are the coordinates of the intersection of axes in projective space?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am following an introductory course in geometry, and I'm working on some problems involving projective geometry. In these problems (and in some similar ones in syllabus), we have to determine the projective transformations which map certain conic sections onto other ones.

A hint I am given for this question reads: *use the fact that $(0:0:1)$ is the intersection of the $X$ and $Y$ axes,* and in an example problem in the syllabus, they use the fact that *$(1:0:0)$ is the intersection point of the $X$ axis and the $Z$ axis.* This confuses me.

In my mind, the axes obviously intersect at the point $(0, 0, 0)$ (in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ at least). Looking at it now I would think that the point $(0:0:0)$ is not really defined in projective space, but the other so called 'points of intersection' seem plainly wrong to me.

The point $(1:0:0)$ for example. Is that not represented in Euclidian space by the line which runs along the $x$-axis? I find it difficult to see how this would be a point of intersection, even looking at it projectively.

My question is: how does one define the point of intersection of axes in projective space?

Many thanks,
Hugo.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez My question is: what are the intersection points of the axes in projective space? I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: It may help to sketch the unit sphere in three-space, and to identify the projective axes as _curves_ on the sphere. <> If not, it would be good to edit the question to add the definition of "$X$-axis"; there is a natural guess suggested by the hint you were given, but explicit confirmation would help. (And, as Mariano says, please edit the post body so that the question is stated in the body. This helps further the site objective of accumulating a repository of questions and answers. :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yeah okay man. You are undoubtedly right, but at the same time I feel that your comment is really lame. I totally agree that technicalities are important on a forum like this, but personally I think it would be a shame to see that happening at the cost of answering mathematics questions. While I was wrong, I think my question was quite clear (it's in the title, as you said) and you chose to act like that was invisible: "you did not ask a question". idk